# Notation in set thory.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, notation

Will someone please describe the following set in words. [image: E is supposed to be a set]

Comment: "The $\frac 1n$-neighbourhood of $E$"?

Comment: "The set of points whose distance from $E$ is less than or equal to $\frac{1}{n}$" ?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco I doubt that, even if the horizontal bar is supposed to denote closure of the right hand side

Comment: As it alreday has caused some confusion: Is the overline part of the equation or not? $\let\theta\vartheta\theta_n=\{\,x:d(x,E)<\frac 1n\,\}$ or $\overline{\theta_n=\{\,x:d(x,E)<\frac 1n\,\}}$? Or maybe even $\theta_n=\overline{\{\,x:d(x,E)<\frac 1n\,\}}$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen The identity is a graphic, so my guess is the overline is an artifact, something that should have been trimmed. But only OP can say for sure...

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to put a bar over an equation, does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay:  The symbol $\theta$ is just a variable.  We are going to define a bunch of sets and identify them by a variable.  We could have used any variable.

Next.  The n subscript:  This is an index.  It means the exact properties of the set will be determined by a natural number n.  It also means that we can define a sequence of such sets each determined by a different natural number.

{description of elements} means, of course, it's a set containing elements.

x:condition of x:  Means that the set will consist of all x that fit the condition.

$d(x,E) < 1/n$ is the condition.

d(x, E)< 1/n.  Means the metric distance from x to the fixed point E (which I assumed is defined elsewhere) is less than 1/n.

Note, this 1/n was determined by the index n.

So the set is all the points that are less than distance 1/n from E.

In other words, the open neighborhood or ball of E of radius 1/2.  Often this is written as $N_{1/n}(E)$ or $B(E, 1/n)$ or some other notation.  Here they are simply using the notation $v_n$ and we are allowing for a multitude of different sets $\theta_n,\theta_m, \theta_7$ etc. which all a bunch of open balls centered around E.

===========

Ah, I should have realized this.  E is usually a notation for a metric space or a set, and I *did* think it was weird to use the notation E as a point but ...  d(x,y) is the distance between points so I figured...

Anyway E is a metric space or set and d(x, E) = the minimum distance between the point x and any point of E.  If $x \in E$ d(x, E) = d(x,x) = 0, so presumable x is not in E.  Then colloquially we say d(x,E) is the distance from x to E. (i.e. the distance for x to the nearest point(s) of E).

So $\theta_n$ is all the points within 1/n from E.  Basically, this is extending the set E "out" by 1/n distances.

Comment: Please don't call "theta" a "fancy v"

Comment: That's $\theta$?  Well, what do you know?  I always draw my thetas with the line extending through the body.

Comment: There's $\theta$ and $\vartheta$ and of course $\Theta$. (Oops, seems I spoiled `\theta` for this page by `\let\theta\vartheta` in my first comment far above)

Comment: okay, $\theta$ it is.

Comment: $\let\theta\theta$ Wait we can screw up notation with "\let". Theta ain't $\theta$ no more?

Answer (score 2):

1. Everytime you have a set, described as $$A=\{x: P(x)\}$$ where $P(x)$ is some statement containing $x$, this means that $A$ is the set of **all elements $x$ such that $P(x)$ is true**. This case is no different.
2. $\overline A$ usually means the **closure** of $A$.

Comment: Since the horizontal bar extended across the equal sign I thouhgt it would be a graphics artefact? Also, $\{\,x:P(x)\,\}$ is a priori a *class* rather than a set.

Answer (score 0):

It might be of some use to know the definition of $d(x,E)$ first :
$$d(x,E) := \inf \big\{ d(x,e) :~~ e \in E\big\}$$

Therefore $\left\{ x :~~ d(x,E) < \frac{1}{n}\right\}$ is the set of all $x$ lie at a $d$-distance strictly less than $\frac{1}{n}$ of some point of the set $E$.

Comment: Don't forget the overline: it's the *closure* of what you describe.

Comment: @BrianO But $\overline{A=B}$ makes little sense ...

Comment: I too am under the impression that the horizontal bar is a graphic artefact.

Comment: Hadn't noticed that I confess! Just that it was way too long on the right. Nevermind:) no idea if that bar is supposed to mean anything or if it's a mistake or an artifact.

Comment: It's got to be an artifact, doesn't it?